# Json object contain json array parsing

Tags: java, json

Am using a function to add list items,name ,id into a jsonobject and returning that object into called function,and getting all the way..But i am little confused with parsing of that json string.

```
JSONObject obj = abcobj.function();

public JSONObject function()
{
  jsonobj.put("test",list);
  jsonobj.put("name",name);
  jsonobj.put("id",id);
  return jsonobj;
}

System.out.println("Json object"+devid);
```

***Output***

```
 {"test":["test","test1"],"name":"xxxxx","id":"1234"}
```

please help me to parse this object

Comment: Do you want to use Java to parse it?

Answer (score 3):

create an instance of JSONObject class and using for loop through each json item and finally storing each json data in variable.

> ```
> JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(jsonData);
>   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();    
>   JSONArray jsonList = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("test");
>  for (int i = 0; i < jsonList.length(); i++) {
>           list.add(jsonList.getString(i));
>    }
>  String str_name = jsonRoot.getString("name");
>  Integer str_id = Integer.valueOf(jsonRoot.getInt("id"));
> ```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [org.json.](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) Java parser, here's how to do it:

```
String jsonData = "{\"test\":[\"test\",\"test1\"],\"name\":\"xxxxx\",\"id\":\"1234\"}";

JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(jsonData);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();    
JSONArray jsonList = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("test");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonList.length(); i++) {
  list.add(jsonList.getString(i));
}

String name = jsonRoot.getString("name");
Integer id = Integer.valueOf(jsonRoot.getInt("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to parse? If what you want is to get access to the data inside test1, for example, you need to retrieve test[1] then get the data out of there. If you are wondering why are you seeing the name of the object in the list, my guess is that you have a toString where you are only displaying the name of the object, in the class that you are adding to that list.

Another thing to note, that json that you showed to us in the output, is not valid json. Or rather, it has got 2 fields with the same name, which is not recommended as an object can only have 1 field with the same name.

Can you post all the code that you are using for creating and parsing the json? Also, have you considered using GSON? A very simple and powerful JSON library from Google.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to store the interestKeys in a list.

Using the [**org.json**](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) library:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{interests : [{interestKey:Dogs},{interestKey:Cats}]}");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("interests");
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
    list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("interestKey"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use one of the following approaches:

The first one: define a domain object and use frameworks to "deserialize" string into this object. GSON/Jackson should work for you here

Example:

```
public class MyObject {
   String [] test;
   String name; // the second name in example is wrong json 
}
```

Now use GSON like this:

```
 MyObject obj = new Gson().fromJson(yourStringComesHere, MyObject.class);
 obj.name
```

Of course you should provide getters/private access to the data fields in the MyObject     class, but this pretty much explains the idea.

Alternatively you can keep working with JSONObject, it should have getters, like this:

JSONObject jsonObject = getObjectSomehow();
   jsonObject.get("name");

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
Object s=devid.get("test");
ArrayList<String> d=new ArrayList<>();
d=(ArrayList<String>) s;
for(Object i: d)
    {
    System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println(obj.get("name"));
    System.out.println(obj.get("id"));
*output*

test
test1
xxxxx 
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to parse json:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

  Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
  ArrayList<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();
  String jsonString;
  Gson gson = new Gson();

try {
        jsonString = "{"test":["test","test1"],"name":"xxxxx","id":"1234"}";
        map = (Map<String,Object>) gson.fromJson(jsonString, map.getClass());
        testList = (ArrayList<String>) map.get("test");
 }
 catch (Exception e) {


 }
```